# Print a simple triangle using list and loops in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

Given n = 5

My triangle should look like this :

```
       *
      *+*
     *+++*
    *+++++*
   *********
```

What i have tried :

```
n = 5

for x in range(0, n):
     for y in range(0, n-x-1):
        print(end = "")
     for z in range(0,x+1):
        print("*", end = "")
     print()
```

but the result is like this :

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Thanks for help and maybe some explanations

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_triangle(n):
    print(" "*(n+1)+"*")
    for x in range(0, n):
        for y in range(0, n-x):
           print(end=" ")
        print("*+", end="")
        for z in range(0,x):
           print("++", end = "")
        print("*")
    print((1+2*(n+1))*"*")
print_triangle(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
def tr(n):
    print(" "*(n-1)+"*")
    for x in range(1, n-1):
        print(" "*(n-x-1), end="")
        print('*', end="")
        num = ((x-1)*2) +1
        print("+"*num + "*")
    print(((2*n)-1) *"*") 

>>tr(5)
    *
   *+*
  *+++*
 *+++++*
*********
```